# VB.NET - Storing/Retrieving Blobs (images) in Access

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access, blob

Thought I had the solution, now I'm kicking a new error.

I'm trying to store and retrieve images in MS Access via VB.NET. I know, I know, keeping the images in the file structure would be a better way. Not my call and the specs can't be changed.

Had some help from jmcilhinney (thanks!), seems I can get the image into an Access table. But I can't seem to save the file back to disk. The last line of code(picture2.Save) is throwing the following error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

"Additional Information: A generic error occurred in GDI+"

That's really... Generic. Here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
   'Put the image into Access
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jason_000\Documents\System.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DATATABLE (FilePath, FileName, FileObject) VALUES (@FilePath, @FileName, @Picture)", connection)
    Dim Picture As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Satan.jpg")

    connection.Open()

    'Create an empty stream in memory.
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
        'Fill the stream with the binary data from the Image.
        Picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        'Get an array of Bytes from the stream and assign to the parameter.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "C:\")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", "Satan.jpg")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", stream.GetBuffer())
    End Using


    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()




    'Get The Image Out of Access
    Dim connection2 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jason_000\Documents\System.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT FileObject FROM DataTable WHERE PK = @ID", connection2)

    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 4)

    connection2.Open()

    Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command2.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

    connection2.Close()

    Dim picture2 As Image

    'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)

        'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
        picture2 = Image.FromStream(stream)
    End Using

    picture2.Save("C:\Users\jason_000\Desktop\SatansBack.jpg")
```

Comment: @downvoter really? what is wrong with this question?

Comment: No doubt. Somebody's been downvoting every post I make. He'll probably downvote this comment LOL!

Comment: that error is because you close the stream before you save the image.  With Images and Bitmaps created from a stream, the stream must remain open for the life of the image. See [remarks at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx). Move the SAVE up inside the USING and that part would work.  The answer below is a better alternative to cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `stream.GetBuffer()` can return an array which is bigger than the data that it contains. You should use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", stream.ToArray())` instead.

Even better will be to just read the data from file in a byte array, not in an image object, so instead of

```
Dim Picture As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Satan.jpg")
```

you should use

```
Dim Data As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Satan.jpg")
```

And instead of

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", stream.GetBuffer())
```

you will use

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", Data)
```

Also, in this case you will not need the `stream` variable (`Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream`).

Comment: Tried that, still getting the error on the last line of code (picture2.Save). Thanks anyways!

Comment: That was the ticket! Did away with the Image datatype altogether and went with IO.File.WriteAllBytes. Thanx bosonix!